# 'Invalid paramater number' error for pdo query with regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pdo

I've been using PDO for years now, but today is my first time using REGEX in a query. I'm getting an odd error when I try to use PDO properly.

The original query with IN works.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tags AS t LEFT JOIN images AS i ON i.id=t.image WHERE t.tag IN(?)";
$args = array('apple');
$rslt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$rslt->execute($args);
```

I want to search for any instance and modification of the word, not just the word on its own, so I'm trying REGEXP. The same query with REGEXP and embedded arguments works.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tags AS t LEFT JOIN images AS i ON i.id=t.image WHERE t.tag  REGEXP 'apple'";
$args = array();
$rslt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$rslt->execute($args);
```

When I try to move the argument to the $args array, I get the error 'Invalid paramater number'.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tags AS t LEFT JOIN images AS i ON i.id=t.image WHERE t.tag  REGEXP '?'";
$args = array('apple');
$rslt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$rslt->execute($args);
```

Is this not allowed? I've seen others do it with bound values, but since I don't know how many words I'm going to be searching on, I don't really want to write code to bind each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake. It should be `REGEXP ?` not `REGEXP '?'`.